# How can I remove allowed values of a list field?

Tags: 7, paragraphs

I set up a *List (Text)* select list field in a paragraph bundle. I set some values to test. I want to remove them (so I can populate them programmatically) and I deleted the content using the fields, but I still get this message.

> Allowed values list: some values are being removed while currently in use

These values are not used. I did use them to test, but I deleted them after testing.

How can I remove those values?

Answer (score 1):

Have you got revisioning on for your content types? If so then those revisions will still be using the paragraph. You'll need to delete the revisions too before you can make the change